# Heating and battery Drain issue in ubuntu 22

Tags: 22.04, battery, overheating

I recently updated my system from Ubuntu 20 to Ubuntu 22, and I’ve been experiencing significant heating problems and rapid battery drain since the update. This issue is affecting the usability and performance of my laptop.

My laptop - MSI GF63 8RC

Any help regarding this.